# Label frequency property not working in amChart

Tags: amcharts

[image]

We have using stacked amChart(serial) for showing graph. We have added a filter functionality for graphs.The user can filter data according to week,month and quarter. We have using bootstrap. The amChart is placed in div having class "col-md-6". When user select week filter the amchart having 52 lables.At that time the bars are  very thin. It is very difficult to analyze the data.So we want to increase the label frequency. We have set label frequency into 5 but it is not changing

```
AmCharts.makeChart("stackedChart", {

                     "type": "serial",
                     "theme": "light",
                     "legend": {                            
                         "position": "right",
                         "useGraphSettings": true,

                     },
                     "dataProvider": data,
                     "valueAxes": [{
                         "stackType": "regular",
                         "axisAlpha": 0.3,
                         "gridAlpha": 0,
                         "position": "left",
                         "gridCount": 5
                     }],
                     "plotAreaFillAlphas": 0.1,                        
                     "graphs": graph,
                     "categoryField": "Period",
                     "categoryAxis": {
                         "gridPosition": "start",                           
                          "labelFrequency": 5,


                     },
                     "export": {
                         "enabled": true
                     }


                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`labelFrequency` is probably not the best way to go about it. It basically means display a label every X'th grid line.

What you are looking for is pre-zooming the chart. For that you can use [`maxSelectedSeries`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#maxSelectedSeries). I.e.:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("stackedChart", {
  ...
  "maxSelectedSeries": 5,
  ...
});
```

Also, if you are going to have pre-zoomed chart, you will also need the means to scroll it. For that you need to add a scrolbar:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("stackedChart", {
  ...
  "maxSelectedSeries": 5,
  "chartScrollbar": {},
  ...
});
```

Here's the whole chart with the above applied:

```
AmCharts.makeChart( "stackedChart", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "maxSelectedSeries": 5,
  "chartScrollbar": {},
  "legend": {
    "position": "right",
    "useGraphSettings": true,
  },
  "dataProvider": data,
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "stackType": "regular",
    "axisAlpha": 0.3,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "gridCount": 5
  } ],
  "plotAreaFillAlphas": 0.1,
  "graphs": graph,
  "categoryField": "Period",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start"
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
```